# Error when plotting in Jupyter Lab with @interact and JavaScript issue

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-lab, ipywidgets, jupyter-extensions

[image]

I'm encountering an error while trying to plot in Jupyter Lab using the **`@interact`** decorator. When I execute my code, I receive the following JavaScript error message:

```
Failed to load model class 'VBoxModel' from module '@jupyter-widgets/controls'
@http://localhost:8888/lab/extensions/@jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager/static/134.402424ef4079078b2e0e.js:1:74985
...
```

I attempted to fix the issue by checking my configurations, but everything seems to be in order. Here are some additional details:

- Operating System: macOS M1 Pro (Ventura 13.4)
- Development Environment: Anaconda Navigator (2.4.1)
- Python Version: 3.11.4

I've tried updating the Jupyter-related packages and widgets multiple times, but the problem persists. I've attached a screenshot showing the update process.

Furthermore, I have a log file named **`jupyterlab-debug-_ek2188n.log`** generated by the terminal (zsh) when I ran **`jupyter lab build`** in the previously activated conda environment. Here's the content of the log file:

```
[LabBuildApp] Building in /Anaconda3/anaconda3/envs/jupyter-env/share/jupyter/lab
[LabBuildApp] Node v18.16.0
...
```

As a beginner, I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide in resolving this issue. If necessary, I can also share my **`.zsh_history`** file to provide more context. Thank you in advance for your help